# SeaweedFS k8s 100 hdd

Tags: kubernetes, storage, seaweedfs

Looking at seaweedfs, want to replace minio. Main reason - seaweedfs can easily be enlarged with any amount of nodes/disks.

But have several questions close to my infrastructure. Now I have 2 nodes with 100 hdds each (HPE CL5800), they were included to kubernetes cluster.

So, how it will be better to run seaweedfs upon these nodes? Make `storageClass` from all disks? Or to export all disks with `mountPropogation` inside pod? Or third interesting option?

Minio is running with mountPropogation now, one pod on node, all 100 drives. If one of the drives will go out, we don't need to restart the pod.

Are there any best practices to run seaweed on such infrastructure?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Update: SeaweedFS has a CSI driver now https://github.com/seaweedfs/seaweedfs-csi-driver

You can use this driver to provide disk spaces for other pods in the Kubernetes cluster.